# Navigator back in react native

Tags: reactjs, native, back

i want that when i click on back (on the phone button - android)
its will be back to the previews scene
this is my code:

```
    class students extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: false,
            userstatus: false // false - guest, true - user
        };
        I18nManager.forceRTL(true)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(() => {
            self.setState({
                value: true
            });
        }, 3000);
    }

    _renderScene(route, navigator) {
        if (route.id === 1) {
            return <Userarea navigator={navigator} userstatus={this.state.userstatus} />
        } else if (route.id === 2) {
            return <Main navigator={navigator} userstatus={this.state.userstatus} />
        } else if (route.id === 3) {
            return <Register navigator={navigator} userstatus={this.state.userstatus} />
        }
    }

    _configureScene(route) {
        return CustomSceneConfig;
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.state.value){
            return <Loading/>;
        } else {
            return (
                <Navigator
                    initialRoute={{id: 1, }}
                    renderScene={this._renderScene.bind(this)}
                    configureScene={this._configureScene} />
            );
        }
    }
}
```

i tried use "onBack" but its not helped me...
Now when i clicked back in my android its exit the app...
i want back button to android and iphone both

tnx

Answer (score 1):

it all depends on how you added the page you navigated to, if you used navigator.push() you can use navigator.pop() or navigator.goBack() (which will keep the current page.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#pop

if that is confusing and you're familiar with react router from web 
this is pretty similar and does not require a deep knowledge in flux/redux

https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux

Comment: yhea, i know i need navigator.pop() but how to do listner to android outside button ?